# How can i filter laravel eloquent query in one to many relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am stuck in eloquent query!
I want to show all related data only user with certain role_id.
bookings:(has created_by field)

Booking Model::

```
 public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','created_by');
}
  public function division()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Division','division_id');
}
```

and users table has a column role_id. 
View:

```
 @if(!empty($allBooking) && count($allBooking)>0)
                @foreach($allBooking as $key=>$booking)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$key+1}}</td>

                        <td class="text-capitalize">
                            @if($booking->division && $booking->division->division_name )
                                {{$booking->division->division_name}}
                            @else
                                N/A
                            @endif
                        </td>
```

How can i get all booking data with role_id 1 ?
I want to use pure eloquent to get division name too from another one to many realtion.

> ```
> ===============================edit
> ```

Budget Model::

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','created_by');
    }
    public function subHead()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\SubHead','sub_head_id');
    }
```

SubHead Model ::

```
 public function head()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Head','head_id');
}
```

Work Model::

```
    public function subHead()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\SubHead','sub_head_id');
}

public function bookings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Booking','work_id');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `role_id` is in the `users` table, use `whereHas()`:

```
Booking::whereHas('user', function($q) use($roleId) {
    $q->where('role_id', $roleId);
})->get();
```

Comment: It works! What if i want to filter by a field from division table too?

Comment: @Fawel in this case just add a similar `whereHas()` or `orWhereHas()` for the `divisions` relationship.

Comment: Like that? $data = $this->budget->whereFiscalYear($r->fiscal_year)
            ->whereHas('subHead',function($q) use($head){
                $q->whereHas('head',function ($q) use($head){
                    $q->where('id',$head);
                });
            })->get(); @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: I'm not sure about the code because I don't see any `budget` or `head` or `subHead` in relationships you've shown in your original question.

Comment: Edited question with models.Booking has amount and year field, How can i get all budget data with sum of subhead wise booking ? User will select head and year, and i have to show sub head, sum of that subhead found in booking table for that year. I tried this but can't find way where i will add count!  `$head=$r->head_id;
        $data = $this->budget->whereFiscalYear($r->fiscal_year)
            ->whereHas('subHead',function($q) use($head){
                $q->whereHas('head',function ($q) use($head){
                    $q->where('id',$head);
                });
            })->get();`